# Meteor reactive on collection.find

Tags: meteor, reactive-programming

So, I know that if I do a collection.find(), it's actually reactive and will update the information displayed when there's new data in the collection.

Like if I do something like this:

```
Template.test.helpers({
  test: function() {
    return MyCollection.find({});
  }
});
```

So, I know that my {{test}} part in the HTML will be updated properly.

But I need to parse that data on the client side before. Is there a way to call a function every time the find function is called?

Is there anything that could be like:

```
function() {
  MyCollection.find({}, function(result) {
    // this is executed each there's new data
    // do some stuff with result
    Session.set("mySessionVar", newResultData);
  });
}
```

And then, place Session.get("mySessionVar") in some helper function.

Comment: You can pass one helper to another if that helps. So: `{{parseTestHelper test}}` where `parseTestHelper` is another helper in the list that does the parsing.

Comment: I will try that! That could actually be the right solution for me.

Comment: @below9k please post what you said in your comment as an answer. I will accept it and upvote it. That's exactly what I wanted.